# Exception '-[__NSCFString containsObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000140a440' was thrown while invoking canOpenURL on target

Tags: react-native

Exception '-[__NSCFString containsObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000140a440' was thrown while invoking canOpenURL on target LinkingManager with params (
"about:srcdoc",
41622,
41623

I am getting this while trying to use WebView in my React-Native app. I see this error only in iOS, android runs fine. This is my WebView code.

return (

```
    <View style={{ flex: 1, }}>
        <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, }}>
            {renderHeader()}
            <WebView  
             source={{uri: 'https://medmate.com.au/frequently-asked-questions/'}}  
            renderLoading={() => (
                <ActivityIndicator
                    color={colors.BUTTON_BG}
                    size='large'
                    style={{position: 'absolute',
                    width: '100%',
                    height: '100%',
                    backgroundColor: 'white',
                    alignSelf: 'center',
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                    top: 0,
                    left: 0,
                    right: 0,
                    bottom: 0,
                    zIndex: 10,
                    elevation: 1000,}}
                />
            )}
```

/>
This is the Simulator error.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObQRO.png

This is my package.json files:

1.https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9ftl.jpg
2. https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbnOf.jpg

Comment: once check  originWhitelist                                                                   
https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Reference.md#originwhitelist

Answer (score -1):

check originWhitelist and add a *.

originWhitelist={['*']}

https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Reference.md#originwhitelist